# How to paginate more than 10M of records efficiently

Tags: mysql, performance, pagination, cursor, offset

I need to paginate more than 30M users which are hosted on MySQL. I'm displaying 15 users per page, but it's quite slow. My goal is to access to any random page and load it in a few ms.

At the beginning, I was using the offset method for MySQL, but as I said, is quite slow (and a bad idea for sure). Then I moved to ElasticSearch, but you still have some window limit, so you are limited. After that, I have been checking different ways like the "cursor" method, but I can not access to any random page. For example, we start at the first page, and we have 100000 pages, I would like to access the 4782th page, and load it in a few ms. With the cursor method, I'm just able to access the next && prev page, and the "scroll" method doesn't fit what I really need.

My users' ID are not sorted just by ID, so I can not use it as a delimiter. Already thought about [Late row lookups](https://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/)

I don't mind to move all my data to a new DB (but would be to find different solutions). Here Amazon does it really well (https://www.amazon.com/review/top-reviewers)

Query using offset:

```
SELECT users.* from users
WHERE users.country = 'DE'
ORDER BY users.posts_count DESC, users.id DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 473
```

PD: My user list is almost in real-time, so it's changing every hour.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm just curious about your use case. Why would someone need to access the 40K-th user on page 2667, just like that at random?

Comment: For example if I'm you want to find your user in that list, and after knowing your position is almost at the end, you will need to write by hand that page.

Answer (score 1):

"access the 4782th page" -- What is the use case for this?  "Pagination" is useful for a few pages, maybe a few dozen pages, but not thousands.

[Next], [Prev], [First], [Last] are useful.  But if you want a random probe, then call it a [Random] probe, not "page 4782".

`OFFSET` is inefficient.  Here is a discussion of an alternative:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Meanwhile add `INDEX(country, posts_count, id)`

Comment: It's not about what is the use case for this, because as we can see in that link, Amazon does it really fast and also a lot of big companies (Zalando, Aliexpress..etc). The issue is how to solve it efficiently nowadays. Your discussion link is really useful when you have just one or two params to sort.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this with Elasticsearch is to add a linearly increasing field (e.g. `sort_field`) to each of your records (or use your ID field if it's linearly increasing). The first record's field has value 1, the second 2, the third 3, etc...

Then, if you sort by that field in ascending mode, you can use the [`search_after` feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) in order to access any record directly.

For instance, if you need to access the 4782th page (i.e. record 71730 and following), you can achieve it like this:

```
POST my-index/_search 
{
  "size": 15,                      <--- the page size
  "sort": [
    {
      "sort_field": "asc"          <--- properly ordering the records
    }
  ],
  "search_after": [ 71730 ]        <--- direct access to the desired record/page
}
```

Under certain circumstances, it is also possible to make the sorting even faster by leveraging the [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) capability.

**Note:** deep pagination is not something Elasticsearch has been built for. The solution above works, but can have some shortcomings (see comments) depending on your context. It might not be the best available technology for what you need to do.

Comment: So at the end, you are adding a new column, just to set up the "ranking". But as I said, that ranking is changing almost in real-time and I think will be really expensive to update that ranking every time. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Then Elasticsearch is not the technology you're looking for. It's a search engine at heart, not a database and [deep pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html) is not one of its priorities

Comment: Yep, it's what I thought. That's why I need some ideas

Comment: Ok, but you can probably remove the `elasticsearch` tag, then